# How to set user preference via cookies for dark mode?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, local-storage, blogger

On my Blogger blog, I am trying to create a dark mode light mode toggler. I have successfully created the toggler, but now I want to save the user preference so that if a user left with dark mode, he/she will get dark mode when he/she will get dark mode only after returning.

This is the code I have written so far. I need help with the local storage/ cookie thing to save user preference.

```
<b:tag aria-label='Dark Mode' class='darkmode-toggle' id='modetog' name='a' onclick='myFunction()'><i class='fas fa-adjust'/></b:tag>
<script>
    /* Dark Mode */
var clicks = 0;
$(&#39;#modetog&#39;).click(function() {
if (clicks % 2 === 0){    
document.querySelector(&#39;body&#39;).classList.add(&#39;isdark&#39;);
} else{  
document.querySelector(&#39;body&#39;).classList.remove(&#39;isdark&#39;);
}++clicks;
});
</script>
```

P.S.: I am still learning JavaScript, sorry for asking stupid questions. I didn't understand even after searching on the internet.

Comment: You can use hasClass to do it.

if(body has class is dark) remove isdark. then add isdark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the localStorage api ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)):

```js
// Code to save setting
localStorage.setItem('darkTheme', '1'); // Here you can put any string you want, I just chose 2 understandable ones

// Code to retrieve the setting
localStorage.getItem('darkTheme');
```

---

Edit: implementing the request of the comment down here

You can simply loop through the components of your page and set their style to match the selected theme (although loading different css is more performant and advised, it would require editing a good chunk of your current code)

```js
const theme = localStorage.getItem('darkTheme');

if (theme) {
// Runs only if darkTheme is set to 1, or any truthy value
// (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy for reference)

    document.querySelector('body').classList.add('isdark');
    clicks++; // This is to keep your theme switcher working: if the page starts dark and the user clicks to change the theme you want to revert back to light
}
```

To incorporate this in your code:

```js
/* Dark Mode */
var clicks = 0;

const theme = localStorage.getItem('darkTheme');

if (theme) {
// Runs only if darkTheme is set to 1, or any truthy value
// (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy for reference)

    document.querySelector("body").classList.add("isdark");
    clicks++; // This is to keep your theme switcher working: if the page starts dark and the user clicks to change the theme you want to revert back to light
}

$('#modetog').click(function() {
if (clicks % 2 === 0){    
    document.querySelector('body').classList.add('isdark');
    localStorage.setItem('darkTheme', '1');
} else{  
    document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('isdark');
    localStorage.setItem('darkTheme', '0');
}
++clicks;
});
```

Comment: I also want to display dark mode if local storage has darkTheme 1. How to do that? Thanks btw

Comment: This works partially, but when a dark user wants to switch to light and clicks it once, and refreshes, it shows dark only. Pls make the necessary changes, thank you. P.s.: I am really a noob and still learning stuff, soory if my stupid requests piss you

Comment: I got the problem. if (theme) statement is making the problem. Change it to theme==1. It worked doing so. Thanks a lot and edit the necessary changes and I'll click the green tick again. Thanks!